# Extracting an AMI from AWS to local

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I am trying to extract an AWS AMI onto my local to have it as a disaster backup.  I know we can save it into S3 and restore it, however my goal is to take it out of AWS and save it elsewhere.

Your thoughts are much appreciated!
Thank you :)

Comment: If you have it in s3, what denies you to download it locally?

Answer (score 1):

As Mark said above, In order to export the AMI to your local, you need to first transfer the AMI to an S3 bucket and then can download it using AWS Cli.

Complete steps/pre-requisite/considerations are available on the below link:

[Export AWS AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport_image.html)

Answer (score 0):

You would export it to S3 first. Then you can very easily download the file from S3.